# Set inner table border in HTML

Tags: html, css, border, css-tables

How do I set the "inner border" - the border between different cells.

By setting style attributes I manage to control the outer border, but the inner border just stays the same gray color and the same width. What attributes should I tweak to control the inner border?

Answer (score 14):

For ordinary table markup, here's a short solution that works on all devices/browsers on BrowserStack, except IE 7 and below:

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; }

td + td,
th + th { border-left: 1px solid; }
tr + tr { border-top: 1px solid; }
```

For IE 7 support, add this:

```
tr + tr > td,
tr + tr > th { border-top: 1px solid; }
```

A test case can be seen here: http://codepen.io/dalgard/pen/wmcdE

Comment: This is a very fine piece of code. I am grateful for its simplicity.

Comment: this layout breaks if for example, if the last row only receives one `td`, how do you fix this ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to style the `<td>` element.

Take a look at the [W3C website](http://www.w3.org/Style/Tables/examples.html)